# How to give path to mounted drive in ubuntu

Tags: steam, ubuntu-21.04

Iam using ubuntu 21.04 and installed steam in it.

Now i want to backup some of my games into mounted drive.

Since my root partition is getting full.

The mounted drives are ntfs partition of my nvme
(since i changed from windows to linux os i considered keeping my ntfs partion drives with it's data).

I did checked /dev in it i only found nvme partion files .

So if there is a way around  to give steam  the path of my mounted drive please tell me ...

> > > > > > > > > > > 